# How can I create a custom output from input which find command finds?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to read a value from user (vcodec). Now, `find` command finds files and stores them in `{}`. I want to use paramater extensions to create a custom output. But of course I got the error `'bad substitution'`. How can I solve this? Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash

read vcodec
find -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:v "$vcodec" "${{}%.*}.mkv" \;
```

Comment: Some finds don't have a default path. Specify '.' explicitly.

Comment: It has not been pointed out clear enough yet: `{}` is not a shell variable or parameter; it's something that `find` expands while calling `ffmpeg`. Therefore the syntax `${{}%.*}.mkv` doesn't apply. The current shell tries to expand this piece of code before `find` even runs. It makes no sense (`{}` is not a valid name for a variable) and you get `bad substitution`.

Comment: So how can I do another way ?

Comment: Like in the answer: supply `{}` (expanded by `find`) to `bash`, it becomes like `$2` in the context of the new shell and then `${2%.*}.mkv` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
read -p 'vcodec >>> ' vcodec
find . -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$2" -c:v "$1" "${2%.*}.mkv"' -- "$vcodec" {} \;
```

Comment: The `$vcodec` bit has to be passed into the in-line script: `bash -c ' ... ' bash "$vcodec" {} \;`  (Then use both `$1` (the codec) and `$2` (the pathname)).

Comment: Or just `export vcodec` in the calling shell, but that's cheating.

Comment: ı give the `vcodec` variable "copy", but I got this error: `copy: No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, this works. However I don't know what  `--` do before `{}`

Comment: `find . -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:v copy "${1%.*}.mkv"' -- {} \;` this is the solution for me.

Comment: So `{}` used for inputs `$1`?

Comment: `{}`is a positional parameter for bash

Comment: I also use `export vcodec` to reach the solution, but I didn't know how its work neither  :(

Comment: POST fixed, was an issue. Try to understand the logic of positional parameters. copy is the first, so $1. {} is $2

Comment: Not true about "end of parameters". `--` becomes `$0`. The existence of the first non-option argument after `-c` (i.e. `'ffmgeg …'` in this case) implies end of options. `--` *before* `'ffmpeg …'` would do what you think it does now. The current `--` could be `sh`, `sh-find` or `whatever`.

Comment: Ah, I use this from years, but I learnt something new, thanks