# Is there a way to safely break a long command line, which is inside quotes?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, ffmpeg

I wrote a command that is a little complicated. Because there are several `' '` and `" "` quotes. And escaping conditions like `'\''` (that usage is obligatory for some reasons. I researched it a lot). And I try to break the line with `\` inside any quotes, I got problems that `find` doesn't recognize `ffmpeg` and the rest as a command. Also in `shellcheck.net` it says: "Don't break lines inside quotes.". How can I do this safely? Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
a="copy"
v="h264"
exts="srt"
f="50"
n="Arial"


sudo find . -iname "*.mp4" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a "$2" -c:v "$3" -vf \
"subtitles="${1%.*}.$4":'\''force_style=fontsize="$5",fontname="$6"'\''" \
-map_metadata -1 "$1.${1##*.}" -hide_banner' -- "{}" "$a" "$v" "$exts" "$f" "$n" \;
```

Comment: While I agree shellcheck.net may complain, I see no general reason for `find` not to "recognize `ffmpeg` and the rest as a command". A backslash inside a single-quoted argument stays literal, even if just before a newline; the newline stays literal. Backslash+newline pairs get to `sh -c` and this is the shell that uses the backslashes to turn many lines into one. The outer shell "sees" a single command only because newlines are single-quoted. Note that in the context of the inner shell `${1%.*}.$4` and few other parameters are *not* double-quoted. *This* may fail.

Comment: How are not double-quoted? I have lack of this information.

Comment: In the context of the inner shell `subtitles=` is double-quoted and the quoting *ends* just after. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, my bad...

Comment: What if you just fix the quotes? `-exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a "$2" -c:v "$3" -vf "subtitles=${1%.*}.$4:force_style='\''fontsize=$5,fontname=$6'\''" -map_metadata -1 "$1.${1##*.}" -hide_banner' inner-sh "{}" "$a" "$v" "$exts" "$f" "$n" \;` Note I don't know `ffmpeg`, I re-positioned the escaped single-quotes only because of examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34644126/10765659). Used `inner-sh` because of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/557107/108618#comment1035071_557112). You can place backslash+newline anywhere inside the single-quoted string.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly. What if I use ```--``` instead of ```inner-sh```? Isn't the function of ```sh -c``` done before the ```--```already?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/q/1514011/432690#comment2291293_1514016), part b. But `inner-sh` vs `--` is not really important here, only a good practice. What if you just fix the quotes? Then you can use [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560851/108618) to make the outer shell concatenate lines, or place backslash+newline pairs anywhere inside the single-quoted string to make the inner shell concatenate lines. Anyway I think the quoting needs to be fixed in the first place.

Comment: Okay the quoting correction and backslash+newline did the trick. But [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560851/108618) didn't work. Cause I think actually don't get the ```concatenate``` thing. Thanks for all of your comments by the way!

Comment: Does the answer work now, *after* you fixed the quoting?

Comment: Yes. It works...

Comment: So the real problem was with the quotes. Still your question is about "breaking a long command line". Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). It's good we had the actual code to debug and solve X. Still the answer that moves backslash+newline pairs to the outside of the quoted content may make shellcheck.net not complain (but I haven't checked this). For this reason it may be a valid answer to Y. Note the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560863/108618) tried to fix the quoting (X) but it *failed* in bringing it to your attention. Not very educative.

Comment: I see. I want to use ```sh``` instead of ```bash``` to make my scripts more portable. Maybe I didn't attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider ending the line with a single quote immediately followed by the backslash, and starting the next line with the single quote (no spaces!), like

```
...'\
'...
```

Comment: I tried like this ```sudo find . -iname "*.mp4" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a "$2" -c:v "$3" -vf '\
'"subtitles="${1%.*}.$4":'\''force_style=fontsize="$5",fontname="$6"'\''" '\
'-map_metadata -1 "$1.${1##*.}" -hide_banner' -- "{}" "$a" "$v" "$exts" "$f" "$n" \;``` but it didn't work. I got errors like ```fontsize="$5",fontname="$6"'" -map_metadata -1  : No such file or directory``` And I tried different variations, and I got another error like ```\\\n\t-c : No such file or directory``` :((

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash for your script instead of sh, you can use an array to hold the arguments to find -- arbitrary whitespace is allowed in an array literal.

```bsh
find_args=(
    .
    -iname "*.mp4"
    -exec sh -c '
        ffmpeg \
            -i "$1" \
            -c:a "$2" \
            -c:v "$3" \
            -vf "subtitles=${1%.*}.$4:'\''force_style=fontsize=$5,fontname=$6'\''" \
            -map_metadata \
            -1 "$1.${1##*.}" \
            -hide_banner
    ' -- "{}" "$a" "$v" "$exts" "$f" "$n" \;
)

sudo find "${find_args[@]}"
```

If you're getting `ffmpeg: not found`, then it's located in a directory not in root's PATH. Use the full path to ffmpeg instead.